# Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm

Getting error in PhpStorm as

> Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting error on PHPStorm as "Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version"

Just need too change the JS language version to ECMAScript 6 which is under

: File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript

and make sure you restart your IDE.